How to use vm.overcommit_memory=1 without getting system hung?
I am using vm.overcommit_memory=1 on my linux system which has been helpful to allow starting multiple applications which otherwise wouldn't even start with default value of 0, however, sometimes my system just freezes and seems the OOM killer is unable to do anything to prevent this situation. I have some swap memory which also got consumed. I've also noticed some instances when system is unresponsive, even the magic SysRq keys don't work. Sorry, no logs are available at this time to include here.
In general, is there any configuration or tunable that can get the OOM killer to kill the highest memory consuming process(es) immediately without ever letting the system go unresponsive when using vm.overcommit_memory=1?

Reading the fine manual is always a good place to start - although you should try the authoritative sources first:

man 5 proc on your local machine
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

I would guess that you have some idea what vm.overcommit_memory=1 means - its an instruction to always grant memory requests regardless of the current usage. In such a scenario, OOM killer is always going to start terminating processes.
So even without these hangs, your system is going to be unreliable with services / programs being terminated randomly. For most of us, this is not a desirable state.

otherwise wouldn't even start with default value of 0

It is remotely possible that some of these programs might allocated and use more memory at startup which they subsequently free up - which would give some scope for a high-wire act playing with the overcommit. But this is highly unlikely and even if it were the case would require a lot of investment of time, effort and code in trying to leverage to get a stable system.
I see no good reason for ever using vm.overcommit_memory=1 unless you actually want to test OOM scenarios.

get the OOM killer to kill the highest memory consuming process(es)

...that's exactly what the default scoring mechanism already does.
Don't use vm.overcommit_memory=1. You could use vm.overcommit_memory=2 and tune the overcommit ratio if you know what you're doing and are prepared to invest a lot of time into testing. Or just stick with vm.overcommit_memory=0. But the biggest wins come from:

Adjusting the config of your applications to use less memory
Adding memory (RAM or swap)


I hope this helps You Docs
vm.overcommit_ratio=99 - use 99% of memory
vm.overcommit_memory=2 - only allow applications to start if there is enough memory determined by the above command
vm.swappiness = 10

vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1  - Logs processes consuming memory during OOM.
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 1 - Prioritizes killing the process causing the allocation failure.

